# How to fit a mixed model in R with both R and G side effects?

Tags: r, nested, mixed-models

I want to fit a covariance pattern model in which outcomes are correlated within clusters as well as within repeated measures on subjects, who are nested within the clusters.

In SAS I would fit the following model:

```
PROC MIXED DATA = test ;
    CLASS cluster_id subject_id time ;
    MODEL outcome = time / DDFM = KenwardRoger;
    RANDOM intercept / subject = cluster_id V VCorr ;
    REPEATED  / SUBJECT = subject_id(cluster_id) TYPE = AR(1) R RCorr ;
RUN;
```

How can I fit this model using R? I have looked through the nlme package documentation, but have not figured it out.

Comment: do you have some sample data?

Comment: Can you expand this to use fewer acronyms and instead use full descriptors. I get the sense that you are expecting R users to share your SAS-based shorthand.

Comment: The model I want to fit will have random effects to account for correlation of outcomes within the same cluster and uses a correlation structure (I chose autoregressive order one for example) for the residuals to account for correlation between outcomes within the same subject.

Comment: @pyne Here is a link for some data I simulated for this model. <https://pitt.box.com/s/orj4zuk1v0cnf73z1lcj9igbr4nf1f2g>